# Wait for default entrypoint.sh in docker container to finish before running commands

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Im trying to configure my `docker-compose.yml` file to run some commands on every startup using the command option, but it is important that these commands do not run before the default `docker-entrypoint.sh` of the image (`wordpress:latest`) have finished executing its scripts.

The trouble i'm running into is that these commands execute too early, or even overwrites the default scripts in the `docker-entrypoint.sh`.

What is the correct way to handle a case like this?

Comment: entryporint scripts will always run before any commands

Comment: This is what i thought, but there is a crucial step of the `docker-entrypoint.sh` that is not completed before my commands are run. And this step is moving the wordpress files from somewhere on the container to the `/var/www/html` folder.

The first line in my commands is a command for installing wordpress but this crashes as the files are not present yet

Comment: you need to provide the dockerfile and how you start the container ....

Comment: Heres the entrypoint from the image i'm using `https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh` and theres a snippet of the service inside my `docker-compose.yml` file:

`https://pastebin.com/amtX9e6S`

I am referencing a custom docker file there, but it is basically just the default wordpress:latest that also pulls down composer.phar and wp-cli.phar